# How to sort strings in a file numerically

Tags: powershell, batch-file

In my batch script there will be a temporary file with the notes that are in a section (gotten from a json file but that doesn't matter)

Format:
(position of note in milliseconds),(kind of note),(if not 0 the note is supposed to be held and it's the time  milliseconds the note is supposed to be held)

(the format is not important)

but some of the time it's not sorted

Example:

```
2285.71428571429,0,0
2367.85714285714,0,0
2455.35714285714,0,0
2576.78571428571,1,0
2757.14285714286,1,0
3046.42857142857,0,0
2962.5,1,0
3128.57142857143,0,0
3216.07142857143,0,0
3298.21428571429,1,0
3380.35714285714,1,0
2669.64285714286,3,0
2882.14285714286,3,0
```

So I would like to sort them but the sort command cannot sort them properly

Expected results:

```
2285.71428571429,0,0
2367.85714285714,0,0
2455.35714285714,0,0
2576.78571428571,1,0
2669.64285714286,3,0
2757.14285714286,1,0
2882.14285714286,3,0
2962.5,1,0
3046.42857142857,0,0
3128.57142857143,0,0
3216.07142857143,0,0
3298.21428571429,1,0
3380.35714285714,1,0
```

The line items does not need sorting. The line needs to be sorted.

Comment: The last 2 numbers don't acually matter
It needs to sort **each line**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state, the Format is not important So I opted for table output. Seeing as your input seems to be csv format, we can use `powershell`'s `Import-Csv` fucntion to pull in the data delimit on `,` and then use `Sort-Object` to sort decimal numbers accordingly.

Here we are setting headers for `Col1` to `Col3` (as per your example), then sorting on `Col1`, with the remainder of the columns in tact.

```
$file = Import-Csv -Header "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" -delimiter ',' test.txt
$file | Sort-Object { [double]$_.Col1 } | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

**Result:**

```
PS Z:\> $file | Sort-Object -Descending { [double]$_.Col1 } | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

Col1             Col2 Col3
----             ---- ----
2285.71428571429 0    0
2367.85714285714 0    0
2455.35714285714 0    0
2576.78571428571 1    0
2669.64285714286 3    0
2757.14285714286 1    0
2882.14285714286 3    0
2962.5           1    0
3046.42857142857 0    0
3128.57142857143 0    0
3216.07142857143 0    0
3298.21428571429 1    0
3380.35714285714 1    0
```

You can run directly from `cmd` as:

```
powershell "$file = Import-Csv -Header "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" -delimiter ',' test.txt; $file | Sort-Object { [double]$_.Col1 } | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap"
```

**Result:**

```
PS Z:\> $file | Sort-Object -Descending { [double]$_.Col1 } | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

Col1             Col2 Col3
----             ---- ----
2285.71428571429 0    0
2367.85714285714 0    0
2455.35714285714 0    0
2576.78571428571 1    0
2669.64285714286 3    0
2757.14285714286 1    0
2882.14285714286 3    0
2962.5           1    0
3046.42857142857 0    0
3128.57142857143 0    0
3216.07142857143 0    0
3298.21428571429 1    0
3380.35714285714 1    0
```

Or hybrid into `batch-file`  and joining variables with `,` to give you the same output result as input:

```
@for /F "skip=3 tokens=1-3" %%i in ('powershell "$file = Import-Csv -Header "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" -delimiter ',' test.txt; $file | Sort-Object { [double]$_.Col1 }"') do @echo(%%i,%%j,%%k
```

**Result:**

```
Z:\>sort_object-Int.cmd
2285.71428571429,0,0
2367.85714285714,0,0
2455.35714285714,0,0
2576.78571428571,1,0
2669.64285714286,3,0
2757.14285714286,1,0
2882.14285714286,3,0
2962.5,1,0
3046.42857142857,0,0
3128.57142857143,0,0
3216.07142857143,0,0
3298.21428571429,1,0
3380.35714285714,1,0
```

Comment: This really works but This is what I found:
This really works but This is what I found:
=====================

Col1             Col2 Col3

----             ---- ----

2285.71428571429 0    0   

2367.85714285714 0    0   

2455.35714285714 0    0   

2576.78571428571 1    0   

2669.64285714286 3    0   

2757.14285714286 1    0   

2882.14285714286 3    0...   <-----

2962.5           1    0   

3046.42857142857 0    0   

3128.57142857143 0    0   

3216.07142857143 0    0   

3298.21428571429 1    0   

3380.35714285714 1    0   




====================

Comment: It's hard to read but in one of the numbers from col3 there's a 0 that also has a "..."
Something i can note is that the line that has the "0..." It's the last line from the original string in the file. The original file also has blank lines at the end that doesn't really do anything

Comment: It is difficult to tell why withou seeing an actual example of the input data. If you can post the last part of the data in your question by copy and paste, I can have a look at why.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the input file and output from powershell:

https://pastebin.com/rnuqG7Uh

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem. perhaps copy the file, clear the majority of the content and leave 4 or so lines of the bottom lines (including empty lines), then upload the file so I can have an actual copy of the file.

Comment: [Here's the unedited file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/efqpv5rbkqb2qxz/section_info._notes_temp.temp?dl=0)

Comment: ok, it is because of the table being truncated, fixed by adding `| Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap` see edit.